# Find the largest leading coefficient of $P(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

Let $ P(x)=Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E$. Find the largest value of $A$ which satisfies $0 \leq P(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$.

I have no idea on how to start. It looks quite weird(I have never seen such type of problems). How do I start? Thanks.

Comment: This could be a way to start : $0\le P(0)=E\le1$ ; $0\le P(1)=A+B+C+D+E\le1$;$0\le P(-1)=A-B+C-D+E\le1$.

Comment: Nice, but it finally gave me $1 \geq A+C \geq -1$.

Comment: Another thought: you can suppose that $P(c)=1$ for some $c$ in $[-1,1]$, because if $\max P(x)=M<1$, then $0\le P(x)/M\le1$, but its leading coefficient is greater than the leading coeff. of $P(x)$.

Comment: OK, but how does that help me?

Comment: It helps because now you know that $P(x)-1$ has a root in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: I realized that you can also suppose that $P(x)$ has a root, because you can take $0\le P(x)-\min P(x)\le 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notice that we can assume that $P(x)$ has a root in $[-1,1]$ and that exists $c\in [-1,1,]$ such that $P(c)=1.$
Suppose now $0\le P(x)\le1$ for every $x$ in $[-1,1]$, then 
$$0\le \frac{P(x)+P(-x)}{2}\le1.$$
We have that $\frac{P(x)+P(-x)}{2}=Ax^4+Cx^2+E$, so we can suppose $B=D=0$ and $0\le E\le1$.
If $C\ge0$ then we must have $A\le1$. So suppose now $C<0$. Let's now consider the case when $P(\pm1)\neq 0$, so the root of $P(x)$ must be inside $(-1,1)$ and so it must be a local minimum. 
$$P'(x)=2x(2Ax^2+C)$$
so the minima are at $x^2=-C/2A$ and setting $P(-C/2A)=0$ we get
$$A=\frac{C^2}{4E}.$$
Now we use the fact that exists $c\in [-1,1,]$ such that $P(c)=1$ and suppose $c\neq \pm1$. In this case $c$ must be a local maximum, so $c=0$ and so $E=1$. Hence $A=C^2/4$ and finally using the fact that $P(1)=A+C+E=\le1$ we get 
$$A\le4.$$
When $A=4$ we obtain the polynomial
$$P(x)=4x^4-4x^2+1.$$
We should check the case when $c=\pm1$, that is when $A+C+E=1$ and $A=C^2/4E$, but I found (after some computation) that the maximal $A$ is again $A=4$, when $E=1$.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). One can simplify : When you have replaced $P$ by $Ax^4+Cx^2+E$, you are in the case of $I=[0,1]$ and $Q(x)=Ax^2+Cx+E$, $0\leq Q(x)\leq 1$. Now you can consider $H(x)=(Q(1-x)+Q(x))/2$, $H(x)=Ax^2-Ax+F$. We have $H(0)=F$, hence $F\leq 1$, and $H(1/2)=F-A/4 \geq 0$; we get $A\leq 4$, and if $A=4$, $F=1$, that gives the extremal polynomial, and we are done.

Comment: Thank you, this improves a lot my solution and avoids considering different cases.